# automatically remove windows features which are already disabled using cmd and dism

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
dism /online /get-features /format:table|find "| Enabled"
```

the code above gives me the results of the features which are enabled.
output (all features should be disabled except these 'enabled'):

```
Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64                | Enabled
SearchEngine-Client-Package                     | Enabled
```

this is the line required to remove the feature (EdgeCP-amd64 is an example)

```
dism /online /disable-feature:EdgeCP-amd64 /remove
```

i searched for "Enabled" instead of "Disabled" as removed features show up as "Disabled with Payload Removed" and didn't want to try to remove it again.

so my issue is, after playing with this for some time, and still not getting it working, i'm not sure if it can be done with simple piping, or if a for/loop is required. would prefer no extra files written, also no enabledelayedexpansion (if possible).

ty. rich.

currently using Windows Technical Preview build 9860.

Comment: any reason to not use powershell ? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205471.aspx

Comment: this works ok. this question can be considered answered. :)

`for /f %%a in ('dism /online /get-features /format:table ^|find "| Disabled"') do (dism /online /disable-feature:%%a /remove)`

Comment: So write this as answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 3):

this works ok.

```
for /f %a in ('dism /online /get-features /format:table ^|find "| Disabled"') do (dism /online /disable-feature:%a /remove)
```

Answer (score 0):

same solution with powershell on Windows10 PS>5.x

```
foreach($f in (dism /online /english /get-features /format:table |find "| Disabled")) { iex ("dism /online /disable-feature:" + ($f.Split(" "))[0].Trim() + " /remove") }
```